# I can't find out how to make my function work (CountIF with 2 statements & 2 ranges)

Tags: excel, countif

I can't find out how to make my function work.
Here is my function I try to make work:

```
=COUNT(IF(Sheet1!$V$6:$V$1026;Sheet2!C7, IF(Sheet1!$J$6:$J$1026;Sheet2!B7)))
```

This is what I want to do: (Example)

**Sheet 1**

```
    J         V        
6  test      Low
```

**Sheet 2**

```
      B      C           cell with function
7    test   Low                  1
```

What is wrong? Is there an other way to do the same thing?

Additional question, when I don't want to use 1026 as final range but when i want to use a range till the last cell whit a value, how do i do that?

Comment: You could try the `COUNTIFS()` function instead, which may well do what you are looking for. See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Additional question, when i don't want to use 1026 as final range but when i want to use a range till the last cell whit a value, how do i do that?

Comment: It is usually best to ask additional questions as new questions. In this case, however, I think you'll find that `INDIRECT("B"&COUNTA(B:B))` will give you the address of the last cell in column B - see [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Excel_last_cell_in_a_column_with_an_amount_in_it). I can't test it right now because I don't have a copy of Excel to hand, but I suspect that it will only work if you don't have gaps in the column. More complicated solutions that deal with that problem are discussed [here](http://www.grbps.com/Excel7.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is this:

```
=SUM(IF(Sheet1!$V$6:$V$1026=C7,IF(Sheet1!$J$6:$J$1026=B7,1,0),0))
```

This is an array function so you must use Crtl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter for it to work.

One of the main problems with you formula is that IF statements are comprised of three pararmeters: a test followed by true and then false separated by a comma. In your formula you have no tests and you are using a semi-colon.

Comment: Hey, I already used to COUNTIFS function as mentioned in the comments by Simon. Thanks anyway.